# Entity Framework - Extend Class with One to Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to extend an existing entity with another class that has a new property that will map to another table?

Say we have a entity class named Foo. Foo has various properties and should remain closed for modification; however, a new property needs to be added to extend Foo with a collection that relates to that class, let's call that derived class Bar.

```
public class Bar: Foo { }
```

Bar has a new property that is a collection:

```
public class Bar: Foo {
    public ICollection<Tar> { get; set; }
}
```

Bar's property should be mapped to another table.

I've looked into the inheritance with EF:

- Table per Hierarchy
- Table per Type
- Table per Concrete class

These all create new tables to represent Foo and Bar or adds a discriminator column to the existing Foo table.

Ultimately, what I would like is a Single table, Foo, that links to another table, Tar, via a derived class, Bar.

Comment: What you "ultimately" want is not correctly described from a database perspective: Bar doesn't "link to" Tar. Tar "links to" (has a foreign key to) Bar. Therefore, what you describe is the shown class model implemented as TPT.

Comment: I would like Bar to essentially replace Foo. Then query off of Bar instead of Foo. I'm not sure how to properly setup up a TPT in this case. Would you mind showing me an example? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that this is just not possible. :/